# LaTeX Error using \@textsubscript

Tags: errors

The following sequence worked in earlier versions of MikTeX (2.9.3959)

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand*\textsubscript[1]{%
    \@textsubscript{\selectfont#1}}
%  \newcommand{\@textsubscript}[1]{%
%    {\m@th\ensuremath{_{\mbox{\fontsize\sf@size\z@#1}}}}}
\makeatother
```

But now throws the following error (in MikTeX 2.9.7152-x64):

```
 LaTeX Error: Command \@textsubscript already defined.
              Or name \end... illegal, see p. 192 of the manual.
```

Is there an obvious reason for this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The `\newcommand{\@textsubscript}` will fail because `\@textsubscript` is already defined by the LaTeX kernel. You need to use `\renewcommand` if you want to redefine something. But why do you want to redefine that? The definition you showed is exactly the same as LaTeX's...

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik It is now ...

Comment: Many thanks!  Is there a reason this would have worked in older distributions?  I inherited a file that had that line but per your suggestion, I suppose I can remove this segment from the code.

Comment: @D.Neal Well, depends on which version of LaTeX you have. That is the current definition of `\textsubscript` and `\@textsubscript`, so if you have an up-to-date LaTeX kernel (`ltxbase` package in MiKTeX) then you can remove those lines. As Joseph said, that was not always the case; apparently the change dates back to 2014...

Comment: @Phelype - Thanks!

Comment: @D.Neal You're welcome :-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was due to an old patch to the LaTeX code which is now built into the format.

Comment: I don't see why this is off-topic: its perfectly answerable